# Password should not be update if user not give any value in password field laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on edit profile and i want that password should not be update if user not give any values in password field now if user not enters any value then password update automatically

Here is my method

```
    {
$this->validate($request, [
           'name' => 'required|max:255',

         ]);

        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $input = $request->all();
        $user->fill([
        'name'           => $request->input('name'),
        'password'       => bcrypt($request->input('password')),
        'def_timezone'   => $request->input('def_timezone'),
        'address_line_1' => $request->input('address_line_1'),
        ])->save();

    session()->flash('msg',trans('successfully Updated.'));
    }
```

Please Help to fix the issue Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
'password' => $request->password ? bcrypt($request->password) : $user->password,
```

Also, you can use `update()` method instead of `fill()` and `save()`. With this approach empty values will be ignored:

```
$user->update($request->all());
```

Answer (score 0):

You must do something like this into your edit validation

```
'password' => 'min:6|max:50',
```

So the user cant send an empty password to your db:

If you want to check before you update the user password , it will be good to have another field into your view the Old_password so you can check if the user remember the old password ans os can change it to a new one .
here is my example my update function:

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
{


    $update_user = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'min:2|max:35|string',
        'surname' => 'min:2|max:35|string',            
        'email' => Sentinel::inRole('Admin')?'required|email|min:3|max:50|string':(Sentinel::check()?'required|email|min:3|max:50|string|unique:users,email,'.$id:'required|email|min:3|max:50|unique:users|string'),
        'old_password' => 'min:6|max:50',
        'new_password' => 'min:6|max:50',
    ]);

    if ($update_user->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()
                    ->withErrors($update_user)
                    ->withInput();
    }

    $user = User::find($id);
    if ($user) {

         if(!empty($request->file('image'))){
                $file = $request->file('image');
                $destinationPath = public_path() . '/upload-client/profile_image';
                $filename = str_random(6) . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $unwanted = array("\'", "+", "%");
                $filename  =str_replace($unwanted, "", $filename);

                $uploadSuccess = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);   
                $user->image_path=$filename;
            }
          if($request->name){
          $user->name=$request->name;
          }
          if($request->email){
          $user->email=$request->email;
          }
          if($request->old_password){
            if (Hash::check($request->old_password, $user->password)){
                 $user->password=bcrypt($request->new_password);
             }else{
              Session::flash('message', 'Your old password is incorrect.');
               Session::flash('status', 'error');
              return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['old_password', 'your old password is incorrect']);
             }
          }

        $user->update();
        if ($request->role) {
          $user->roles()->sync([$request->role]);
        }
        Session::flash('message', 'Success! User is updated successfully.');
        Session::flash('status', 'success');

    } 


  return redirect()->back();
}
```